# Python defaultdict works not as expected

Tags: python

I found a very strange thing of defaultdict, below is the source code of type defaultdict

```
class defaultdict(dict):
    ...
    def __init__(self, default_factory=None, **kwargs):
```

It shows that type defaultdict accept an optional parameter `default_factory`, I want to build a defaultdict, where the value is also a defaultdict, below is my test code

```
from itertools import combinations

x = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
print(x)
print('someKey in x:', x['someKey'])
y = defaultdict(default_factory=lambda: defaultdict(int))
print(y)
print('someKey in y:', y['someKey'])
```

The output is

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f90406e2440>, {})
someKey in x: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
defaultdict(None, {'default_factory': <function <lambda> at 0x7f90406e9b90>})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{path-to-my-code}.py", line 31, in <module>
    print('someKey in y:', y['someKey'])
KeyError: 'someKey'
```

why it's different, I thinks `x` and `y` should have same behaviour

Comment: Where did you find this source code? It's implemented in C - https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c

Comment: The default factory *must* be passed as a *positional argument*.

Comment: thank you, now I know why